# Windows 2012 server not executing socket.on

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to learn to use NodeJS and JavaScript to replace at least some of my Perl code.

I need to create a socket and have a server/listener accept data sent from a client.

The problem I am having is that under Windows 2012 server, the listener code below just completely ignores the socket.on command, but it works fine under CentOS.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am missing?

```
var net = require('net');
var fs  = require('fs');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    console.log('At : ' + (new Date()) + '\nA client connected to server...');
    console.log('IP addr : ' + socket.remoteAddress);

    // Process data sent from client
    socket.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('Reached socket.on function.\n');

        // Following command reads the data stream from client
        var string = ('IP addr : '+ socket.remoteAddress + ' sent on ' + (new Date()) + ' : ' + data.toString()+'\n');
        console.log(string);

        // Following command writes the data stream to a file
        fs.appendFile('client-data', string, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('Data saved from client...');
        });
    });

    // This section sends data back to client, close socket, and 
    // resets to accept new socket connection
    socket.write('\n<svrdata>\nData received by : HS-AD02 \r\n</svrdata>');
    socket.pipe(socket);
    socket.end();

    console.log('The client has disconnected...\n');

}).listen(10337, 'hs-ad02');
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Perl? I hope you're not discarding perfectly good Perl code just because it has become a little less popular recently?

Comment: Borodin:  My apologies on the PERL tag.  That was a mistake.  Actually I am not discarding PERL at all.  I just have to rewrite a number of PERL scripts anyway, so I thought I would do in NodeJS so that I could learn.

Comment: It is spelled ***Perl***. You wouldn't like to see your own name in all-capitals I am sure! And since you are aiming to learn, you should pay a lot more attention to layout and white space in your code. You should be proud of the way a program *looks* and how clear it is to read

Comment: Understood.  And Thank you.  However, I still need help with the problem?  Are you not able to provide any insight as to why that function will work under Linux/CentOS and not Windows 2012?

Answer (score 0):

In the code above the problem has a very simple solution.
Under Windows the two lines of 
    socket.pipe(socket);
    socket.end();
Cause the socket to close prior to the receipt of the client data.

Removing those two lines and it works just fine.